# How to get available credits for an Azure Datamarket API Key?

Tags: azure, bing-api

Been using the Bing Search API https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44, but I used up all my credits without noticing, and now I am receiving a message like "The number of fobidden or denied requests per minute from the same IP address has reached the maximum threshold that is allowed. Please try again after".

How can I check if an API Key has sufficient transaction credits on the Azure Marketplace?